# virtualbox, can not ping hostname

Tags: virtualbox, debian, ping

My virtualbox host and guest are both Debian 9. The network configuration is `Bridged Adapter` on `wlp4s0`, my wifi interface.

From the guest, I can not ping a hostname. For example, this produces just on line of output, then "freezes":

```
$ ping google.fr
PING google.fr(par21s17-in-x03.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:808::2003)) 56 data bytes
```

But I can ping ip adress. For example:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=121 time=15.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=121 time=16.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=121 time=16.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=121 time=16.1 ms
```

What is wrong, and how I can fix it? Or if I didn't give enough informations, where should I look at to debug my problem?

Edit: Of course, I can ping hostname from the host.